# Styling MUI Autocomplete with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I have the `AutoComplete` component from [mui](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/) in my code, and I'm using it with their `TextField` component like so:

```
<StyledAutoComplete
  id="xxx"
  clearOnEscape
  options={[...]}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} label="clearOnEscape" variant="standard" />
  )}
/>
```

Where `StyledAutoComplete` is the following styled component:

```
export const StyledAutocomplete = styled(Autocomplete)`
  .MuiAutocomplete-option {
    color: white;
  }
  .MuiAutocomplete-inputRoot {
    color: white;
  }
  .MuiAutocomplete-clearIndicator {
    color: white;
  }
  .MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicator {
    color: white;
  }
`;
```

This works on some styles (such as the text colour *inside the input*) but I don't know how I can for example style the input's `label` or the options' text colour (I tried with `.MuiAutocomplete-option` from the AutoComplete API docs but that doesn't seem to work). Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can design the different parts of the `Autocomplete` component as you are used to.

In order to render the wanted customizations for the TextField (label), you can pass a StyledTextField.

```
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)({
  "& label, & label.Mui-focused": {
    color: "green"
  }
});
```

In the example, we expect the label to be green in unselected and focus state.
In a similar way you can create a StyledOptionBox with your desired changes:

```
const StyledOptionBox = styled(Box)({
  color: "green"
});
```

In this example, the options' text colors are expected to be green.

You will need to pass that `StyledOptionBox` via the renderOption props of your Autocomplete component:

```
<Autocomplete
  id="xxx"
  clearOnEscape
  options={[
    { id: "test", label: "x" },
    { id: "test2", label: "y" }
  ]}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <StyledTextField
      {...params}
      label="clearOnEscape"
      variant="standard"
    />
  )}
  renderOption={(props, option) => (
    <li {...props}>
      <StyledOptionBox>{option.label}</StyledOptionBox>
    </li>
  )}
/>
```

Find it here in a working version:
https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-stallman-tpwkw?file=/src/App.js

More inspiration for changes (and for what is possible) you can find in the [Github's Picker example](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#githubs-picker) in the MUI documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my solution for a customized Autocomplete component:

```
interface Props<T> {
    id: string;
    label: string;
    options: T[];
}

const CustomInput = styled(TextField)<TextFieldProps>(({ theme }) => ({
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.warning.main,
    borderRadius: "4px",
}));

const CustomDropDown = ({ id, label, options }: Props<OptionType>) => {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
            <Autocomplete
                disablePortal
                id={id}
                options={options}
                sx={{ color: "whitesmoke" }}
                PaperComponent={(props) => (
                    <Paper
                        {...props}
                        sx={{
                            backgroundColor: customTheme.palette.secondary.light,
                            color: "whitesmoke",
                        }}
                    />
                )}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <CustomInput
                        {...params}
                        label={label}
                        size="small"
                        color="info"
                    />
                )}
            />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};
```

Also had to overwrite this mui classes in my css file:

```
.MuiAutocomplete-root .MuiAutocomplete-input {
    color: whitesmoke !important;
}

.MuiAutocomplete-popupIndicator {
    color: orange !important;
}
```